# Angular 6 - A Global Check/Validation for all inputs of type Text

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am working on an application using Angular 6.
I am looking for a way to add a global control/Validation for all inputs of type text not to accept specific special characters.
is there a way to apply this check globally for all app inputs of type text or I have to make a directive and it to all inputs ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Make a new component that accepts a string as an input, and belonging html contains only input tag.

use regular expression to validate.

If you do not want to use a new component then you may use a filter like

```
   export class aFilter implements PipeTransform {
        transform(items: any[], aFilter: any, renkFilter:number): any {


            if ( "your regular expression comes here" ) {

                return false;

            }
else return true;

}
```

in html

```
<input> {{variable | aFilter  : yourinputvariable }} </input>
```